# Java JsonPath - Get all paths of attributes that are primitive types

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, jsonparser

I'd like to find all Json paths from a json file where attribute type is primitive (not object or array)

Consider **jsonString**:

```
{
   "header": {
       "version": 2,
       "original": "ori",
       "parent": "par",
       "eventId": 11,
       "correlation": "uuid",
       "timestamp": "03.04.2020",
       "local": true,
       "location": {
           "facility": {
               "id": 3,
               "type": "en"
           }
       }
   },
   "body": {
       "field": 3
   }
}
```

I use the following code:

```
Configuration configuration = Configuration.builder().options(Option.AS_PATH_LIST).build();
List<String> paths = JsonPath.using(configuration).parse(jsonString).read("$..*");
```

***ACTUAL RESULT:*** Pattern **"$..*"** returns me all the paths present in the json:

- $['header']
- $['body']
- $['header']['version']
- $['header']['original']
- $['header']['parent']
- $['header']['eventId']
- $['header']['correlation']
- $['header']['timestamp']
- $['header']['local']
- $['header']['location']
- $['header']['location']['facility']
- $['header']['location']['facility']['id']
- $['header']['location']['facility']['type']
- $['body']['field']

***EXPECTED RESULT:*** I need to get only these ones:

- $['header']['version']
- $['header']['original']
- $['header']['parent']
- $['header']['eventId']
- $['header']['correlation']
- $['header']['timestamp']
- $['header']['local']
- $['header']['location']['facility']['id']
- $['header']['location']['facility']['type']
- $['body']['field']

The Filter should be generic so it can resolve any json format given as input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below JSONPath that will give the path that have objects or array, which you can then exclude from the entire list of JSONPath.

**JSONPath**

```
$..*[?(@.length != 0)]
```

**Java Code**

```
List<String> allPaths = JsonPath.using(configuration).parse(jsonString).read("$..*");
List<String> exludedPaths = JsonPath.using(configuration).parse(jsonString).read("$..*[?(@.length != 0)]");
List<String> primitivePaths = allPaths.removeAll(exludedPaths);
```